# Выводит на экран по 2 раза System.out.println(''')

Tags: java, вывод

Такая ситуация - внутри метода вызываю System.out.println(""); на экран выводит 2-3 раза одно и тоже. До вызова этого метода все нормально, и после тоже.

С чем можно было напутать так, что вывод на экран стал множественный?
Вывод на экран внутри метода идет первой строкой. Просто тестовая фраза типа "привет" и далее идут вычисления.

Так вот  этот привет пишется 2 раза. И все последующие выводы на экран внутри метода идут по 2-3 раза.

Я до этого метода работал с добавлением объектов в список и их удалением путем присваивания null;

Вызов метода `calculatesMainFunctionA`

```
NrezultTask2TypeIntervalSet.calculatesMainFunctionA(rezultTask1TypeInterval,0, numberX);
```

Метод `calculatesMainFunctionA()`:

```
     public void calculatesMainFunctionA(Interval variableInterval, int 
     positionInIntersectionSet, double ourInputX){
        System.out.println("Привет");
        int i = this.intervalSet.size();   


        boolean oneXorTwoX = true;

        if (ourInputX < this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getFrom()){
            variableInterval.putFrom(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getFrom());
            oneXorTwoX=true;
        }
        if (ourInputX >=this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getFrom()){//x>=x1 
            if (ourInputX<=this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getTo()){//x<=x2
                variableInterval.putFrom(ourInputX);
                oneXorTwoX=true;
            }
            else{
                if (positionInIntersectionSet+1==i) {
                    variableInterval.putFrom(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getTo());//return x2
                    oneXorTwoX=true;
                }
                else {
                    if (ourInputX>=this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet+1).getFrom()){//x>=x1n
                        positionInIntersectionSet++; 
                        calculatesMainFunctionA(variableInterval,positionInIntersectionSet,ourInputX);
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        if ((ourInputX-this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getTo())==(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet+1).getFrom()-ourInputX)){//f=f1
                            variableInterval.putTo(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet+1).getFrom());
                            variableInterval.putFrom(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getTo());
                            oneXorTwoX=false;
                        }
                        if ((ourInputX-this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getTo())>(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet+1).getFrom()-ourInputX)){//f>f1
                            variableInterval.putFrom(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet+1).getFrom());
                            oneXorTwoX=true;
                        }
                        else{  
                            variableInterval.putFrom(this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet).getTo());
                            oneXorTwoX=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (oneXorTwoX==true){
            System.out.print("Для заданного числа X результатом будет такое число: ");
            System.out.print(variableInterval.toString(variableInterval.getFrom()));
            System.out.println(" ;-)");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Для заданного числа X результатом будет 2 числа: ");
            System.out.print(variableInterval.toString(variableInterval.getFrom()));
            System.out.println(" и "+variableInterval.toString(variableInterval.getTo()));
        }
    }
```

на экране будет

```
Привет
Привет

Ответом будет 5
Ответом будет 5
```

Comment: Код свой покажите

Comment: у вас метод вызывается 2-3 раза

Comment: Если бы о вызывался 2 раза то было бы на экране так - Привет Ответ Привет Ответ А у меня: Привет Привет Ответ Ответ

Comment: значит у вас там, где //идут вычисления вызывается этот же метод, т.к. рекрсия

Comment: приведите весь код, ну и как бы во всех IDE есть режим отладки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот эта часть кода:

```
if (ourInputX>=this.intervalSet.get(positionInIntersectionSet+1).getFrom()){//x>=x1n
                positionInIntersectionSet++; 
                    calculatesMainFunctionA(variableInterval,positionInIntersectionSet,ourInputX);
            }
```

Вы зовете метод опять, и соответственно получаете опять Привет! и опять ответ.